# Number of configurations in a constrained nested loops and configuration back from serial

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, algorithms, inverse

Consider 4 counters looping the digits 0, 1, 2 to form
the various "configurations", like in :

```
    Config 0:  0 0 0 0
    Config 1:  1 0 0 0
    Config 2:  2 0 0 0

    Config 3:  0 1 0 0
    Config 4:  1 1 0 0
    Config 5:  2 1 0 0

    Config 6:  0 2 0 0
    Config 7:  1 2 0 0
    Config 8:  2 2 0 0

... and so on.
```

(The "faster loop" is assumed to be the one on the left.)

Consider the 2 topics:

```
A) Total number of configurations:
```

We have 3 (number of digits) to the power of 4 (number of counters) configurations in total.

```
B) Find a configuration given its serial number (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5,...) :
```

We can proceed by successive divisions of the serial number by 3 (number of digits)
 and take the sequence of remainders.

For instance, for "serial" 7, we have:

```
   7 / 3 = 2 with remainder 1
   2 / 3 = 0 with remainder 2
   0 / 3 = 0 with remainder 0
   0 / 3 = 0 with remainder 0
```

so we get 1 2 0 0 as in

```
Config 7:  1 2 0 0
```

Same for any serial.

**My question.**

Assume the above nested loop is "constrained" as to have only configurations
with a non increasing sequence of digits: d(j) >= d(any index larger than j)

(like, for instance, in a bi-dimensional loop, you consider only the upper or lower 
triangular part of a matrix of configurations)

Example:

```
    Config 0:  0 0 0 0
    Config 1:  1 0 0 0
    Config 2:  2 0 0 0

    Config 3:  1 1 0 0
    Config 4:  2 1 0 0

    Config 5:  2 2 0 0

    Config 6:  2 2 1 0

... and so on.
```

How do we find:

```
A) Total number of configurations
B) The configuration from its serial number
```

(Clearly, I am interested to the general case of N loops and K digits.)

Comment: To clarify: how config 6 is non-increasing?

Comment: That's right user58697, I typed wrong digits over there (fixed). Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The amount of such configurations is $\binom{n+k-1}{n}$.

A simple combinatorial argument is that when an extra digit ($n+1$) is added, the total is comprised of all "old" configurations (all counters are less than $n+1$) and all "new" configurations (the first counter is fixed at $n+1$); in other words $F(n+1, k) = F(n, k) + F(n+1, k-1)$. Trivial boundary conditions secure the result.

I have no idea on your second question.

Comment: Thank you very much @user58697, very kind. Can you explain a bit more in detail how the recurrence formula you provide yields that number of configurations? About the second questions, the "no idea" is related to a poor explanation of the question from my part, that I should improve, or do you mean, instead, that the question does not look straightforward to answer ?